# Changing the name of the output assembly and package using dnx/.net core

Tags: dnx, .net-core

I have a project which exists in a directory named `Oracle` and I would like the artifacts created to be called `MyCompany.MyApp.Oracle` instead of `Oracle`, what are my options for changing the output assembly name and nuget package name outside of changing the name of the directory?

- I currently have a `MyCompany.MyApp.Oracle.xproj`  next to my `project.json` file
- I've also tried setting `<AssemblyName>MyCompany.MyApp.Oracle</AssemblyName>` in the xproj file but that didn't work
- I've also tried setting `{"id":"MyCompany.MyApp.Oracle"}` in project.json and still no luck

Comment: Please note that things are different now with csproj based solutions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Based on comment of @Victor Hurdugaci

```
"buildOptions": {
    "outputName": "Some.Specific.Assembly.Name"
},
```

You need to put it inside project.json file.
It will produce output with name: Some.Specific.Assembly.Name.dll

Comment: Please be careful Visual Studio still contains some bugs. So custom output name will breaks MVC application startup and discovering tests in Test Explorer.

Answer (score 21):

From .NET Core 1.1 on, which uses `csproj` instead of `package.json`, you should use the `<AssemblyName>` configuration.

Example of `x.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>Name your assembly here</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 7):

Later edit: this answer was applicable to the pre-dotnet releases (dnx). Now it's possible to change the package name.

Old answer:
The only way to change the package name is by changing the folder name.

Comment: I upvoted, but going to keep this open in case alternatives come in.

Comment: Nope, there are no alternatives. Source: I work on the team that builds dnx

Comment: I noticed that. Well here is to hoping this changes.

Comment: really hope this changes.

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Is there an option with dotnet cli?

Comment: In the CLI you can now change the assembly name. So, the package name is still the folder name but you can specify a new assembly name like here: https://github.com/aspnet/dotnet-watch/blob/63a9d64394717f9876e307ccdc67c23ac49a16c7/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools/project.json#L4