# .net core class library dll same as folder name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

when creating a .net core class library I noticed that if the folder name is **"MyLib"** then the dll will be **MyLib.dll** and when you want to reference this project into another project in the same solution you will also have to be like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "MyLib": { "target": "project" },
```

my questions is what if I want my dll to be **Foo.Bar.MLibrary.dll** while still having the folder name "MyLib" (or how are we supposed to do this now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this post:
[Changing the name of the output assembly and package using dnx/.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994365/changing-the-name-of-the-output-assembly-and-package-using-dnx-net-core)

If you want to change the output assembly name, you need to manually modify the project.json file.

```
"buildOptions": {   
    "outputName": "Foo.Bar.MyLibrary"
  }
```